# Optimal way to get Pairs of Objects from a List C#

Tags: c#, list

I have a List of objects named Team and I want the optimal way to get all the possible pairs of objects. I've written an example:

```
public void GenerateMatches(Team team)
    {

        for(int i = 0; i < team.Count-1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < team.Count; j++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Match:" + team[i].Name + " vs " + team[j].Name);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is far from optimal but it works. Any better ideas?

Comment: `Team1 vs Team2` is the same as `Team2 vs Team1` I assume that is what you meant

Comment: Why is this "far from optimal"? What have you tried?

Comment: Willy-nilly you have to enumerate `N * (N - 1) / 2` items for *all possible* pairs; your solution is optimal in this meaning

Comment: You send a `team`, and then iterate it as `teams`?

Comment: @FirstStep sorry for that copy paste error

Comment: To be clear I want the same output but i want to know if there is a better approach!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the solution**:

You will need to iterate `Teams` and take pairs of `currentTeam` with all the **next** indexes:

```
    List<int> MyList = new List<int> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}; // sample input

    List<KeyValuePair<int, int>> MyPairs = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>(); // prepare final result

    for (int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
        for (int j = i + 1; j < MyList.Count; j++)
            if(j < MyList.Count)
                MyPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int> (MyList[i], MyList[j]));
```

Then to **display**:

```
    foreach (var pair in MyPairs)
        Console.WriteLine(pair.Key +" vs "+ pair.Value);
```

Part of the **output**:

[image]

Comment: Your missing some brackets ")"

Comment: Second condition should be `j < Team.Count`, or this will just loop until it throws. It will also create matches where a team plays itself, unlike the original code.

Comment: @CharlesMager Another ops :) I type fast.. Thanks for pointing that out :) Should work now

Comment: @JamieR you **'** re missing a `'` :P Thanks for the edit ;)

Comment: Haha! damn you @FirstStep !

Comment: So this is now essentially no different from the algorithm in the question, surely?

Comment: lol I just noticed that. Good catch.. Well I have an`if statement` instead of `.Count - 1` :P @CharlesMager then this is the most optimal way .. I guess !

Comment: Your approach gives me a key, value pair so it is an improvement but it is very similar( a double loop).I was looking for a faster solution

Comment: @DimitrisKaragiannis glad we were able to help. I don't think there is a better faster way, in a significant difference. Maybe `++i` instead of `i++` but it is not that big difference on these cases. Upvote/Accept if this was helpful

Answer (score 1):

The optimal running time is **n(n - 1)/2**, since this is the number of ordered pairs.
Your solution is optimal.